# is there any alternative for fabric.js in dart flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, fabricjs

I am starting new project which has extensive use of fabric.js functionalities, I need any package or way to handle these things in Flutter.

I have shirt SVG and want to change fabric and color So looking for a way how to deal in dart?

Thanks in advance.